# On Windows 7, my account says "standard profile has been loaded", can't access files. What to do?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

My standard account seems to have corrupted as I've gotten a message saying that a standard profile has been loaded and my files will be deleted when I log off. However I logged off and was able to access the files from my admin account.

So it seems the files are fine, just the user account is not working.

Comment: Are you ok with just having access to your files or you need you application settings also? If you are ok with just the files, you can login using your admin account, copy over the files and then delete the standard user profile. At next login, the profile folders will be recreated

Comment: For now i just want to access the files from another standard account. if there's a quick way to link it to another account than I'd like to try that first, and then see what my next step is, either to try to fix the account or if not then get the application settings, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did: Logged in as admin, created new account, and moved all files to the new account.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Have both users share a similar group, then set the group ownership for those files to the shared group.

To solve your problem: Login as administrator, copy-paste the files into the user directory for your new user. Then make sure to set permissions of all the copied files to be owned by the new user and with read and write access.